# Modify bootstrap version in hawtio

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, hawtio

I am using Hawtio for an internal web application. It talks to my RESTful Tomcat server in the back-end. But currently Hawtio uses Bootstrap2.3.2 version which is no longer supported by Bootstrap foundation.

Is there any way to change Hawtio settings or reconfigure it to use the latest bootstrap version.

Comment: Grab the source code and change the version, and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked on the hawtio issue tracker and answered by Stan Lewis: https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/issues/2060

> yeah, in hawtio v2 we're running against an up to date Bootstrap and have
>   added Patternfly.
>
> To be honest, updating Bootstrap was non-trivial, requiring changes in
>   every HTML partial, I wouldn't want to do it for v1.